# Как в строчке заменить подстроку на другую?

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = "Я пришел домой";
```

Как слово `Пришел` поменять на слово `Приехал`?

Answer (score 3):

```js
var str = 'Я пришел домой';
var res = str.replace('пришел', 'приехал');

console.log(res);
```

Рекомендую почитать больше [о регулярных выражениях в JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).