# Надо написать функцию которая будет менять конкретное слово на другое

Tags: javascript

```
var arr = "Я думаю как написать функцию";
```

поменять `"написать"` на `"напишу"` прошу помочь без использования `replace()`

Comment: Необязательно начинать новый вопрос,  уточните в своём предыдущем вопросе (https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/904642/), что вам нужно менять слова в строке без использования функции `replace()`.

Comment: извините и благодарю за помощь я тут новичок только учусь

Comment: обязательно буду конкретизировать свой вопрос

Answer (score 0):

```js
var input = 'Я думаю, как написать функцию', // исходная строка
find = 'написать', // что заменить
replace = 'напишу'; // на что заменить

// Вариант 1 
// будет работать для слов
var _tmp = input.split(' '); 
_tmp.splice(_tmp.indexOf(find), 1, replace);
console.log(_tmp.join(' '));

// Вариант 2 
// будет работать как для слов, так и для любой подстроки/фразы
find = 'как написать';
replace = 'что напишу';
var wordPos = input.indexOf(find);
console.log(input.slice(0, wordPos) + replace + input.slice(find.length + wordPos));
```

Оба варианта регистрозависимые, поэтому учитывайте это. Если регистр важен, то перед заменой делайте проверку: найдена ли нужная подстрока или нет. В противном случае, если регистр не важен, можно строку и значения для замены приводить к одному виду: `toLowerCase` или `toUpperCase`

Comment: Огромное спасибо за помощь